# Hidden keyboard reset data in my expandablelistview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a expandablelistview with my own adapter, in the childs, i have spinners, edittext etc.
If i edit any of one, when the keyboard hidden, reset the data. How can i fix this?
I put in my manfiiest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".PresupuestoYCierre"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>
```

Any help¿

Comment: Are you persisting textfield and spinner values ?

Comment: No, if have change item in spinner, and before i click in edit text to change de text, when de keyboards hidden, the spinner go to the first value, and text dont save.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is not with keyboard.Its because of list view recycling.

You need to understand the concept of how list view works in android before customizing it with Spinners and EditText. Listview in android wont store any values, you need to maintain a new data-source to store the values entered by user in list then and there.

i hope this url will be helpful.

http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/

http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296